# Aztec Android reader library

Tags: android, library, image-processing, barcode

I'm searching for library (paid or free) that allows scanning and decoding [Aztec codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code) on Android devices.

I already checked  [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) (Zebra Crossing) but this library doesn't support Aztec codes very well.

The library will be used for scanning polish car registration. So Aztec code will look like this:

(it is quite big thats why ZXing can't handle it)

[image: car registration]

Comment: This site need authentication :(

Comment: Sorry, my fault: Typo. Here's the correct link: [Barcode Scanners & Generators](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode)

Comment: Hi Adam, did you found any solution? I have exactly the same problem :(

Comment: @TomaszPikć sadly not. I haven't found any reliable way to scan it, then project was dropped so I never came back to it. As far as I remember https://manateeworks.com was the best from all bad solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Adam if you are looking at commercial libraries for Barcode recognition on Android you can try [LEADTOOLS Barcode SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode).The LEADTOOLS SDK has support for a variety or [Barcode Symbologies](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.barcode~ba.topics.supportedbarcodesymbologies.html) including Aztec.

There is a demo application on the Play store that you can test as well. [LEADTOOLS Barcode scanner application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=leadtools.barcodedemo&hl=en)

This demo is developed with the LEADTOOLS Barcode SDK for Android. Here are some screenshots:

[image: Demo application screenshots]

The actual Barcode recognition is done with minimal code:

```
    BarcodeData data = null;
    data = mBarcodeEngine.getReader().readBarcode(<image to be processed>, <screen coordinates to search in>, <barcode symbologies to search for>);
    return data;
```

Source code for the barcode demo above is included in the 60 day trial version of the SDK that you can download from the [LEADTOOLS Site](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main).Please note I work for the company that develops this library.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent some hours under this issue and via lots of testing I found that when you put a white border around the aztec code image, then it works quite well and fast :-) I use it in my app: //for the barcode bitmap (string) scanning: implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3' //FOR THE CAMERA SCANNING: implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0'